# Setting the include search path for autoconf

Tags: autotools, autoconf

I'm trying to cross compile OpenOCD for ARM but can't get past the autoconf stage. Here is the error I get.

```
configure:13765: checking for environ in unistd.h and stdlib.h
configure:13776: arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-gcc -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a8 -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -mthumb-interwork -mno-thumb --sysroot=/home/neil/overo-oe/tmp-2011.03-maintenance/sysroots/armv7a-angstrom-linux-gnueabi -std=gnu99 -c -fexpensive-optimizations -frename-registers -fomit-frame-pointer -O2 -ggdb2 -I/usr/include  conftest.c >&5
CROSS COMPILE Badness: /usr/include in INCLUDEPATH: /usr/include
cc1: internal compiler error: in add_path, at c-incpath.c:425
```

The source includes configure.in and a makefile.am in each src directory. How do I change the header search path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I'm understanding your question, but the include path is setted up in the Makefile.am file. in the macro [name]_CPPFLAGS